# Deleting duplicate file with exactly same filename but different sizes

Tags: files, find

folder_1

```
./a20160606_000000_000021.txt    5KB                                              
./a20160606_000000_000062.txt    5KB  
./a20160606_000000_000531.txt    5KB  
./a20160606_000000_004521.txt    5KB  
./a20160606_000000_003211.txt    9KB  
./a20160606_000000_009451.txt    9KB  
./b20160606_000000_000001.txt    4KB  
./b20160606_000000_000311.txt    6KB  
./b20160606_000000_000632.txt    8KB  
./b20160606_000000_000008.txt    9KB  
./b20160606_000000_000034.txt    12KB  
./b20160606_000000_000245.txt    12KB  
./b20160606_000000_000333.txt    12KB
```

folder_2

```
./a20160607_000000_000001.txt    9KB                                              
./a20160607_000000_000002.txt    9KB  
./a20160607_000000_000311.txt    9KB  
./a20160607_000000_000500.txt    9KB  
./a20160607_000000_001121.txt    9KB  
./a20160607_000000_004891.txt    9KB  
./b20160607_000000_000021.txt    5KB  
./b20160607_000000_000065.txt    5KB  
./b20160607_000000_000091.txt    5KB  
./b20160607_000000_000134.txt    12KB  
./b20160607_000000_000521.txt    12KB  
./b20160607_000000_001111.txt    12KB
```

I have these folders each folder contain files that are above.The size of each file are indicated in the rightside (folder_1 and folder_2 are on the same folder). My question is how to delete these duplicate files using `find` and file must remain must be the biggest one for each file. The output must be like this:

folder_1

```
./a20160606_000000_009451.txt    9KB  
./b20160606_000000_000333.txt    12KB
```

folder_2

```
./a20160607_000000_000001.txt    9KB   
./b20160607_000000_001111.txt    12KB
```

Comment: How could you have same named files in a directory?

Comment: actually i'dont know most of the data were working are like those, these data were just extracted.

Comment: Perhaps the filenames contain some spaces, or other non-printing characters?  Try running `ls -Q` to show the names in an unambiguous form.

Comment: You can not have files with the exact same name in one directory. Please specify more detailed information like the filesystem you are using and a more detailed directory listing (i.e. `find folder_1 -type f`) to clarify the question.

Comment: I saw some extensions. I've edited my post.

Comment: now how would you decide that you want to keep `./a20160606_000000_009451.txt & ./b20160606_000000_000333.txt` files in folder 1 ?

Comment: @p_p There still aren't any duplicates, at least by name, all the numbers at the end of the names are different. The computer is going to need really specific instructions on what to delete, and so is anyone who tries to answer this.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and explain what you mean by duplicate files. As others have told you, there are no duplicates files in your example. Your output suggests you expect all files to be deleted from both folders except two. Why are those two kept?

Comment: I mean duplicate because when you see the filenames it has many a20160606, b20160606, a20160607 and b20160607 even all of the have different extension(sorry for the word duplicate). I mean i want only to keep one with the biggest size for each file (a20160606, b20160606, a20160607 and b20160607) .

Answer (score 1):

To strictly answer your question, you don't have duplicate files based on filename.

If you want to keep the biggest files based upon the first part of the filename you can use the following `awk` script to get the names of files (with their sizes) which are not the largest based on prefix until the first underscore (a20160606, a20160607, etc.):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f %s\n"| awk '{
NAME=substr($1,0,9)
    SIZES[$1]=$2
    if ($2 > MAX[NAME]) {
        MAX[NAME]=$2
    }
}

END {
    for (x in SIZES) {
        for (y in MAX) {
            if (match(x,y) && SIZES[x] != MAX[y]) {
                printf "%s %d\n", x, SIZES[x]
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

To get a list of names (and their sizes) of the maximums found use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f %s\n"| awk '{
    NAME=substr($1,0,9)
    SIZES[$1]=$2
    if ($2 > MAX[NAME]) {
        MAX[NAME]=$2
    }
}

END {
    for (x in SIZES) {
        for (y in MAX) {
            if (match(x,y) && SIZES[x] == MAX[y]) {
                printf "%s %d\n", x, SIZES[x]
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

There are probably easier ways to achieve this but maybe this will help in getting a list of files subject to removal.